# azure app service custom domain with godaddy issues

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, godaddy

I have 3 azure app services that I need to map to 3 subdomains of our root domain.  I've done similar things in the past without issue but I've not managed to get this to work.  I used the docs and initially did it using CNames after not getting the results I want I am now trying using A records.  I've waited over 48 hours since the last set of changes.

In the azure portal to enable the custom domains you need verify them and then azure looks to make sure that you have entered the correct records to verify ownership.  I believe I done all this correctly.  Here are the settings at godaddy:

[image: A Record settings]

[image: TXT records]

The error I get is an 'ownership' error on the azure side.  I get complete dead ends when try to go to the site.

Comment: Are you sure you're following the right instructions? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-for-Azure-DNS-zones-fbcef2d7-ebaf-40d0-ba1f-cdaeff9f50ef seem to indicate the records look like `MS=...`

Comment: Turns out the domain was registered through godaddy but the client used Wix for the home page.  Wix ended up being where I had to change the settings.  Oddly godday still allows me to edit the DNS settings even though the name servers are managed by another site.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CNAME you don't need any txt entry, so it is often easier. All you need to is make sure that there is the correct CNAME entry pointing back to the azurewebsites.net URL for your site.

To use an A record, you need to setup the A record and a txt record. By the looks of it your text records are wrong. I am assuming your full URL is something like clientadmin.azurewebsites.net? If that is the case then your Host should be "clientadmin" and your txt value clientadmin.azurewebsites.net.

[image]

Source:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name